# git add fails with fatal: src/mytest.pax added file untagged, set correct file tag

Tags: github, git-commit, zos, git-add

When I try to add files to a commit group I get an error.

**Command**: `git add .`

**Error**: `fatal: src/python/files/mytest.pax added file untagged, set correct file tag`

`git —version`: `git version 2.3.5_os390_b013`

**Platform**: z/OS

The problem here is double:

1. I can be a tag in the USS in z/OS because when encoding of the files is different that default you can get automatic conversion. This file is binary and it is not tagged:

```bash
chtag -p *          
t ISO8859-1   T=on  BUZ0N_DEVOPS_SASPGM01_CURR_IN.txt
t ISO8859-1   T=on  BUZ0N_DEVOPS_SASPGM01_FINAN_IN.txt
t ISO8859-1   T=on  SAS_Sample_pack1.txt
t ISO8859-1   T=on  SampleSASFile.sas7bdat
t ISO8859-1   T=on  airline.sas7bdat
t ISO8859-1   T=on  currency.txt
t ISO8859-1   T=on  currency_orig.txt
t ISO8859-1   T=on  financial.txt
- untagged    T=off mytest.pax
- untagged    T=off test123.sas7bdat
```

2. It could be a problem with commit tags.

In any of both cases I don’t have a clue of how to solve it.

Thanks!

I need to add the files and then commit to the repository.

Comment: Is this the Rocket Open Source git? That looks quite old. I know the open source version is at 2.41.0 (see https://zosopentools.github.io/meta/#/Guides/QuickStart if you want to get on a newer version of git)

Comment: Thanks. I’ll look at it. I am in this version because it’s a managed system that I can’t freely update. I’m not sure that this is the Rocket version…

Comment: Check your `.gitattributes` file. Might need to explicitly specify `*.pax` as binary. I believe the older versions of Git from Rocket assume that untagged files are IBM-1047

Comment: Thanks. It didn’t work. I created the file `.gitattributes` cause it didn’t exist. 
**Command:** `$git add .`

And the result is this:
`fatal: .gitattributes added file untagged, set correct file tag`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a `.gitattributes` file, tag it as `ISO8859-1` (easiest way is to just copy an existing text file that's tagged correctly - or use `chtag`) and then add the attributes for `*.pax` to be recognized as a binary file:

```
*.pax binary
```